# WebStorm save custom project templates

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How to save a project as templates?

I found instruction here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/saving-projects-as-templates.html but when I go to tools in main menu I don't have option to save project as template. I found only option save file as template when you select a file.

Anyone know how to save project not file?

Comment: AFAIK it's available in full IntelliJ IDEA but not in WebStorm/PhpStorm **yet**. For example: in PhpStorm it will become available only in 2016.2 version -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31621. Not sure about actual WebStorm (did not found such ticket there) .. but you can try EAP build right now if so desired: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-232/

Comment: Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in WebStorm. Please vote for [WEB-11807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11807) to be notified on any progress with it